# How to filter a row OUT of a JTable using RowFilter

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

Every example I have seen for this uses RowFilter.regexFilter and filters everything else out except the given text. I want the rows of the given text filtered OUT. It doesn't even make sense the other way to me. A coffee filter filters the Coffee grounds OUT, not the other way around.

How do you filter OUT the rows containing the supplied text out of a JTable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`RowFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html) has a static method called [`notFilter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html#notFilter%28javax.swing.RowFilter%29), which takes a `RowFilter` as an argument and returns a new `RowFilter` that has the opposite effect. You could take your `regexFilter` and pass it to `RowFilter.notFilter()`.

Comment: how?  sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(expr));

Answer (score 1):

Got it thanks, `sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.notFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(expr)));`